# Differences between Bootstrap 5.3 colors in develop and production

Tags: css, sass, bootstrap-5, astrojs

I am developing a website with Astro [^2.2.1], Bootstrap [5.3.0-alpha3] and Svelte [^3.58.0].
Almost everything is working properly except for foreground and background colors of some elements (typically buttons). I am not sure what is preventing the production version of the website from looking like the development version of the website.

I am using a custom stylesheet where I define my own bootstrap variables and importing it into my base astro layout. I am not overwriting any default color options just changing the default font, link decorations and breadcrumb options.

In the development version underneath the styling rules for `.btn`
there are two definitions for `background-color`

1. `background-color: transparent`
2. `background-color: var(--bs-btn-bg)`

However in production mode only the first rule exists and the correct background color is not applied

The same issue exists for foreground colors as well except instead of being transparent the first option is `#212529` and the second being `var(--bs-btn-color)`.

If anyone has any information that could help that would be greatly appreciated.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEzr4.jpg) is an imgur link to show an example of the issue

I tried to change how I implemented bootstrap. Removed my custom styling sheet and used only vanilla Bootstrap to no avail. Even removed the npm package totally and still experienced the same issue with CDN

`custom/bootstrap.scss`

```scss
@import '@fontsource/fira-code';
@import '@fontsource/fira-sans';

$font-family-monospace: 'Fira Code', monospace !important;
$font-family-sans-serif: 'Fira Sans', sans-serif !important;

$breadcrumb-divider-color: #808080;
$breadcrumb-divider: url("example.svg");

$link-decoration: none;
$link-hover-decoration: underline;

@import 'bootstrap/scss/_functions.scss';
@import 'bootstrap/scss/_variables.scss';
@import 'bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';
@import 'bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons.css';
```

`Base.astro`

```
---
...
import '@styles/custom/bootstrap.scss'
...
---
<html>
...
</html>
```

`example-component.(astro | svelte)`

```html
<input type='submit' class='btn btn-primary' value='SUBMIT' />
```

Comment: Without your code, or seeing how you are implementing your vars, it will be tough to help you.

Comment: @disinfor what specifically would you need to be able to help? I am not changing anything related to background or foreground colors with my vars. and even when I don't use my stylesheet the colors are still not working properly. I even switched to using a CDN and the colors are still not working properly I can add more snippets to the imgur but. I am literally just importing Bootstrap styling and calling it with the default bootstrap classes.

Comment: I have figured out what the issue was. I was using the astro-compress plugin for astro and upon removal everything started working as expected

Comment: If that is the case, then please provide an answer on the Answer field, it is totally OK to answer your own questions, as from one side it prevents others from spending time for less accurate answers and from another people searching for the same problem will find it, unless you think the question is no longer relevant then please remove it.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out what the issue was. I was using the astro-compress plugin for astro and upon removal everything started working as expected.